# How do you "install" Simple in eclipse?

Tags: java

How do I use simple in eclipse?
Do I add it to the JDK?

http://simple.sourceforge.net
The web site seem to have allot of info on using the methods but little on setting up the library.

I have used C and C++ to set up external libraries before but the Java set up confuses me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In java world, in order to be able to use third party libraries, what you need to do is to add them to your project/application's `CLASSPATH`. In case of Simple, its library file is `simple-xml-2.4.1.jar` that is located inside a folder "jar" within the simple-xml-2.4.1.zip that you would download from Sourceforge.

- Download and unzip the
  simple-xml-2.4.1 Archive. (ZIP file).
  Note that it has a Jar folder that
  contains simple-xml-2.4.1.jar - that
  is the library eclipse and other IDES
  would use to set up the `CLASSPATH`
- Goto your project in project
  explorer.
- Right-click on the project name and
  select "Properties". Alternately, you
  can click on the project name and
  type "Alt+Enter". A window will
  pop-up.
- In the window, select "Java Build
  Path". You will see several tabs,
  including "Source", "Projects" and
  "Libraries".
- To add `simple-xml-2.4.1.jar` to your
  project, click on the "Libraries"
  tab. From there, you can add either
  internal jars or external jars. The
  "Add External Jar" would be to add a
  jar that's on your computer somewhere
  . So choose that button, browse to
  where `simple-xml-2.4.1.jar` is located
  and make sure to add it to your build
  path