# Import Libraries in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, java

I just recently downloaded the dom4j library, but for the life of me I have no idea how to access it. I dropped it in the plug-ins folder and rebooted Eclipse, without success. For some reason finding a straight answer for this is more difficult that I thought it would be.

Comment: Sort of duplicate.. check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677224/how-do-you-install-simple-in-eclipse/4677264#4677264

Answer (score 73, accepted):

No, don't do it that way.

From your Eclipse workspace, right click your project on the left pane -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Jars -> add your jars here.

Tadaa!! :)

Comment: I get a " Folder already exists with a different case" error message.

Comment: Try to `Add External Jars`, then select the jars from the file system.

Comment: Just to clear up a little-- you could create a "libs" directory under your project, then, copy & paste the new .jar file to there.  Then, follow the instructions above to include the new jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the jar, and put it somewhere in your Java project (usually under a "lib" subdirectory).

Right click the project, open its preferences, go for Java build path, and then the Libraries tab. You can add the library there with "add a jar".

If your jar is not open source, you may want to store it elsewhere and connect to it as an external jar.

Answer (score 1):

For the Android library projects, I do it as in the attached screenshot:

Right click the project, select Properties->Android and in the library section click Add. From here you can select the available libraries.

If you are importing a jar file, then importing them as jar or external jar, as other posters posted would work. I prefer to copy/paste jar file in the libs folder (create one if it doesn't exist) and then import as jar.

[image: Adding a library]

Comment: In my case this window is empty. So, an added library in your case has already been mentioned in another place.

Comment: I would suggest to move to Android Studio. Things have changed a lot in these 3 years and Android Studio is a light year ahead of Eclipse. In fact I don't know if Google even supports Eclipse any longer.

Comment: thanks. I was having a battle with Eclipse project for a week and yesterday eventually moved it to AS. After such a long period I hate Eclipse :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get this library into your library and use it, follow these steps:

1. You can create a new folder within Eclipse by right-clicking on your project, and selecting **New Folder**. The library folder is traditionally called `lib`.
2. Drag and drop your jar folder into the new `lib` folder, and when prompted select **Copy Files**.
3. Selecting the **Project** tab at the top of the screen, and click **Properties**.
4. Select **Java Build Path** followed by the **Libraries** tab.
5. Click the **Add JARs…** button and select your JAR file from within the `lib` folder.
6. Your JAR file will now appear in both the `lib` and **Referenced Libraries** folders. You can explore the JAR's resources by clicking **Referenced Libraries**.