# Linking Opencv to my own android project

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

I want to work on an Android project (under Eclipse) using Opencv, I've imported the Opencv library and it's associated samples to Eclipse, as explained here:

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html.

I tested the samples and they work well. But when I create my new own Android project in Eclipse, it can't link Opencv which is placed in the same workspace as the project (i.e. error when I write `import org.opencv.core.*`).

Is there something that has to be done for a new project to be linked with Opencv (`src` and `lib`)?

Comment: you need to add that project from your project through java buildpath check there, there will options to link project with your project.

Answer (score 3):

I recomend you to download the OpenCV prebuild package and follow these [instructions](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/OpenCV4Android).

I don't know if you are going to use C++ for openCV and crosscompile with NDK and JNI library, but that way is quite easy to set up everything. If you need more help about how including C++ OpenCV codes in android projects I can check my codes. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you haven’t included the Open CV library’s in your new project.

I can’t remember the exact step to include libraries in projects but below are a couple of link that might help.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project's_classpath%3F

[Import Libraries in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962559/import-libraries-in-eclipse)