# Android -TripleDESimplementation

Tags: android

I have designed one android application in Eclipse.
In my following code

```
if (!IsNullOrEmpty(BASE_URL)) {
    TripleDesImplementation des = new TripleDesImplementation();
    try {.....}
}
```

I am getting this Exception:

```
Could not find class 'com.vertis.security.TripleDesImplementation',
referenced from method com.vertis.cranedge.MainActivity.getWebServiceURL
```

I have included

```
import com.vertis.security.TripleDesImplementation;
```

Comment: What library are you using? You need to at it to your path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [tell eclipse to use that library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962559/import-libraries-in-eclipse):

> From your Eclipse workspace, right click your project on the left pane -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Jars -> add your jars here.